# Where to put transforming login when using React - Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Quick question, if have transforming logic in my container, is it better to refactor that into my reducers and keep my containers lean. Or is it better to keep a strict api in reducer and have my container logic adhere to that?

Comment: It would be better if you post this in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) with your existing code sample

Answer (score 0):

Use selectors to keep you containers lean. Selectors are used to fetch the data you need, it also increases performance of application.

You can use reselect to achieve this.

[Selectors in redux](https://hackernoon.com/selectors-in-redux-are-a-must-d6b0637c79b7)